# Angular Proxy.Conf.Json not working against multiple apis

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have the following proxy.conf.json, log lines, and api calls.

```
  {
  "/first/api/": {
    "target": "/first/api/",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  },
  "/second/api/": {
    "target": "/second/api/",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }


[HPM] GET /first/api/values-> /first/api/
[HPM] GET /second/api/dummy -> /second/api/

return this.http.get<any>(this.firstApi + 'values')
return this.http.get<any>(this.secondApi + 'dummy')
```

Given I can see log lines, I believe the proxy.conf.json is correctly picked up the api calls, but I'm getting a 404 when the call goes out. The logs only output the target, so it's unclear to me how to compose the url I need, for example:
*localhost/first/api/values*

This works correctly when there's only one api:

```
  {
  "/api/": {
    "target": "/first/",
    "secure": false
  }
```

**Can anybody advise me on further steps to debug?**

---

**SOLVED**

yanky_cranky's answer was correct. As an aide in understanding how his answer related to what I was seeing, I also needed to look at my IIS logs. Here I could see what urls were being called.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly, here you are not correctly leveraging the proxy concept of Angular.

1) **About Proxy** : Proxy can be used to map any request like '/first/api' to target specific "domain" which is out of your reach.
If the apis are not public they will result in cors issue ( which is the property of browser) if the api is pointing to different host : {i.e, either hostname or port or both are different}
With Angular,during our development phase we can leverage the same reverse proxy concept what Nginix provides and target to the right domain.

[More On Proxy Here](https://medium.com/@spencerfeng/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d)

2) your Nginix conf will result in :
following paths :

```
  {
  "/first/api/": {
    "target": "/first/api/",  
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  },
```

/first/api/first/api/ , thus you are getting 404

```
  "/second/api/": {
    "target": "/second/api/",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
```

/second/api/second/api/ , same 404

3) **Correct Config** :

```
 {
  "/first/api/": {

    "target": "http://localhost:{portNo}",

    "secure": false,

    "logLevel": "debug"

  },
  "/second/api/": {

    "target": "http://localhost:{portNo}",

    "secure": false,

    "logLevel": "debug"

  }
```

These api will then target to :

http://localhost:{portNo}/first/api

http://localhost:{portNo}/second/api

cheers (y)

Comment: This is a great answer, but how would I add a config for the Twitter api, which is https://api.twitter.com 

The problem is that I don’t know what to use for the path part. 

So far I have done {“https://api.twitter.com/“: {“target”:” https://api.twitter.com/”,”secure”:true,”changeOrigin”:true}}

I am afraid SO is removing the https part from the Twitter URL. Please can you imagine that the https protocol is there for both values in the json.