# How can i get AccessToken from API of Access Token in linkedin

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

We are integrating LinkedIn login API, we are able to generate authorization code, also able to get access token from browser

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWKtS.png)
but we want this in ajax or HTTP call 
It gives us 200 OK response but not returning the body, but it works in Postman

Comment: Paste the code but rather snapshot

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to pass **body** not as query param but as body object, here is the post call signature :

```
post(url: string, body: any | null, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    observe?: HttpObserve;
    params?: HttpParams | {
        [param: string]: string | string[];
    };
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: 'arraybuffer' | 'blob' | 'json' | 'text';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
} = {}): Observable<any>
```

Refer [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?XXXXX' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: Also, We have passed CORS in http header while post request

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497414/angular-proxy-conf-json-not-working-against-multiple-apis/56497787#56497787) will help you resolve the CORS issue, so after configuring proxy, run with ** ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json **

Comment: We have tried above and enabled CORS in chrome extension

Comment: Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?XXXXX with MIME type application/json

We are getting above in console now

Comment: Can you post your response headers, what all it allows, method, headers, origin etc; you also need to include your content-Type in your request headers

Comment: Just FYI, You put Allow-Access* in server side not at request end. You have to check response headers, what all access are configured, check in postman

Comment: Yes that's fine
but we are not having server access, we are calling *LinkedIn* Signin api to get token