# Problem while deploying Mean-Stack project. Having problem that CORS is blocking every request

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose, mean-stack

I am deploying the Mean-Stack project and while deploying, getting CORS policy error saying that ...

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>       'http://XXX.XXX.X.XX:4000/user/postUserAuth' from origin
>       'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>       preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the
>       Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the
>        wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The
>        credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
>       controlled by the withCredentials attribute

**How can we allow All requests to Express Server and solve this issue?**

**Server We are using for angular is lite-server.**

```
// Used this in Express 
    app.use(cors((
    {
    'origin':'*',
    'credentials':true,
    'preflightContinue':true,
    'optionSuccessStatus':204
    }
    )));

    //Server is logging this 
     "OPTIONS /user/postUserAuth HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "http://localhost:4200/login


    //Angular service class
    export class LogincontrollerService {
      private address = APIEndpoint;
      _LoginURL=this.address+"/user/postUserAuth";
      constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

      // function to for sending request to server with data. 
      getLogin(data){
      return this._http.post<any>(this._LoginURL,data,{
        withCredentials:true
      });
    }

    }
```

Comment: Post Resolving cors from server side, setting "'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials','false'", You need to use [proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497414/angular-proxy-conf-json-not-working-against-multiple-apis/56497787#56497787) from Angular(frontend) side for this, i answered in the link before

Comment: I have tried proxy.conf.json and after that, I have got the error saying this - `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://XXX.XXX.X.XX:XXXX/user/postUserAuth' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1** :  specify the url in `cors` options instead of `*`:

```
const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    credentials: true,
    preflightContinue:true,
    optionSuccessStatus:204

}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

**Note** : This is a part of security. If you want to allow credentials then your Access-Control-Allow-Origin must not use `*`. You will have to specify the exact protocol + domain + port*

**Method 2** : solve CORS  by using the following middileware (if you do not want to allow credentials) :

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // website you wish to  allow to connet    
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','http://localhost:4200/');

    // request method you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET, POST, OPTION, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // request headers you wish to allow 
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization');   

    // set to true if you need the website to include  cookies  in the  request  sent 
    // to the API (eg. in case you can see sessions )
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials','false');

    // pass to the next layer of middleware
    next();

});
```

Comment: try to use this custom  middleware instead of `cors` middileware that you have used

Comment: I am getting the same error that is given above. :(

Comment: @AbhishekKumar try specifying th url instead of `*`

Comment: Set the request header Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*' on client side request.

Comment: How can I set  **Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*'** on client side ??

Comment: Yeah, I tried, but unfortunately, it didn't work. I am getting the same error again that I have given above. It's been the third day that I am stuck in this kind of problem.